# Add "Every other day Constraint" using LPproblem class

Tags: python, pulp

I am trying to optimize the store schedule using the PuLP module, and I have already got the expected result.
But I have only one problem as I need to add one new constrint to it

Through the below code I will be able to distrbute the stores in each day
based on the following constraints

- The Total of Store_demand should not exceed the capcity in one day (1000 or less)
- Every store will be distrbuted based on their Days No. (Store_Days)
  Ex: "S2" should be sheduladed in three days only

Now I need to add one new constraint when the store has only **three days**.
"Every other day" condition to get one day gap

EX:"S2" store

- If it was sheduled on SAT the other days will be MON and WED
- If it was sheduled on SUN the other days will be TUE and THU

```
capacity =  1000
days_list=["SAT","SUN","MON", "TUE","WED","THU"]
no_days_list = range(1,7)
store = ["S1","S2","S3","S4"]
Store_demand = {
        "S1":400,
        "S2":300,
        "S3":250 ,
        "S4":200 ,
    }
Store_Days = {
        "S1":6 ,
        "S2":3,
        "S3":3 ,
        "S4":1 ,
    }

prob = LpProblem("schedule",LpMaximize)
storeVars = LpVariable.dicts("Days",(no_days_list,Store),0,1,LpInteger)
   for d in no_days_list:
        prob += pulp.lpSum([Store_demand[s] * storeVars[d][s] for s in Store]) <= capacity
   for s in Store:
        prob += pulp.lpSum(storeVars[d][s] for d in no_days_list) == store_Days[s]

    prob.solve()

    for vi in prob.variables():
        if vi.varValue == 1:
         print(" On "+days_list[int(vi.name.split("_")[1])-1]+" Pharmacy code: "+vi.name.split("_")[2])
```

Please Advise.

-----------------Updated----------------

```
rob = LpProblem("schedule",LpMaximize)
storeVars = LpVariable.dicts("Days",(no_days_list,Store),0,1,LpInteger)
   for d in no_days_list:
        prob += pulp.lpSum([Store_demand[s] * storeVars[d][s] for s in Store]) <= capacity
   for s in Store:
        prob += pulp.lpSum(storeVars[d][s] for d in no_days_list) == store_Days[s]
          if store_Days[s] == 3:
                prob += pulp.lpSum([ storeVars[d][s]  + storeVars[d][s] for d in no_days_list])  <= 1
  prob.solve()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding additional constraints for all shops that are opened on three days. The following constraint says that the shop cannot be opened on two consecutive days:

```
for s in Store:
    if Store_Days[s] == 3:
        for d in range(1,6):
            prob += storeVars[d][s] + storeVars[d+1][s] <= 1
```

Comment: I think you could keep your previous code as is. Just add the code snippet after your other constraints.

Comment: I tried to copy it as it is, but I got an error "KeyError: 4" the problem in the last line

Comment: sorry, I deleted my comments by mistake, but you can find the latest update I just add an if statement inside the loop,

Comment: Did you just insert the code snippet right above `prob.solve()`?

Comment: I have edited now to be more clear, this updated code help to get consecutive days

Comment: Thanks a lot  , it is now working fine after I replaced <=1 with ==1